# Trained model not loading using pickle module

Tags: python, machine-learning, compiler-errors, artificial-intelligence, pickle

i was training a nlp model, and thendata was very big so, i used google colab to train the model at 50 epochs which took around 3 hours and downloaded it using pickle.dump and now when i am trying to load the model in my machine i get this error :/

name of the model is "**model.pkl**"

### Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15292\2076388884.py in ()
----> 1 model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl','rb'))

c:\Users\balaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\saving\pickle_utils.py in deserialize_model_from_bytecode(serialized_model)
     46         model = saving_lib.load_model(filepath, safe_mode=False)
     47     except Exception as e:
---> 48         raise e
     49     else:
     50         return model

c:\Users\balaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\saving\pickle_utils.py in deserialize_model_from_bytecode(serialized_model)
     44         # serialized as a string by Dense.get_config()) will require
     45         # a custom_object_scope.
---> 46         model = saving_lib.load_model(filepath, safe_mode=False)
     47     except Exception as e:
     48         raise e

c:\Users\balaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saving_lib.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile, safe_mode)
    275 
    276     except Exception as e:
--> 277         raise e
    278     else:
    279         return model
...
--> 256                 raise ValueError(
    257                     f"Expected a {_VARS_FNAME}.h5 or {_VARS_FNAME}.npz file."
    258                 )

ValueError: Expected a model.weights.h5 or model.weights.npz file.
```

can someone help me and find a way so that i don't have to train it again for another 3 hours or something...

Answer (score 0):

did you try `joblib.dump` for converting. This worked for me. Sorry if this was not what you were looking for.

```py
import pickle

#Save the trained model as a pickle string.

saved_model = pickle.dumps(file name, output file name)

#Load the pickled model

pic = pickle.loads(saved_model)
```